# CardView lift on touch

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to make lift effect on cardview click. I found several tutorials on this topic
[this one](http://vickychijwani.me/cardview-material-response/), [this one](http://slides.com/dmytrodanylyk/material-animation#/5/1) and [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400318/custom-button-animation-in-android).
All of this tutorials suggest to create xml file like this

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="6dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item>
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And then put it into res/anim directory. However, when I'm trying to put this code in res/anim/lift_on_touch.xml it gives me error "Element selector must be declared" and suggests to move this file either to animator or drawable directory. I moved it into animator-v21 directory, and there's no error, but it's not working. What should I do in this case?

PS: I put clickable and stateListAnimator attribute to my CardView. This is my CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/lift_on_touch"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/inner_top_guideline" />
```

Comment: This should be a pretty simple fix: copy your xml to `res/animator` directory NOT res/anim, compile and re-run

Comment: @inner_class7 I tried this, still no result

Comment: Remove your internal `<set>` tags that are around the objectAnimator too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping the animator resource with `<set>`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:state_enabled="true"
            android:state_pressed="true">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:propertyName="translationZ"
                    android:valueTo="6dp"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
            </set>
        </item>
        <item>
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                    android:propertyName="translationZ"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType" />
            </set>
        </item>
    </selector>
</set>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same tried to put in the anim folder but actually the folder needs to be animator not anim, just see the below picture (android studio automatically given me the suggestion to shift in animator folder and all worked fine)
[image]

[image]

**res->new resource file -> select animator**

Hope this helped cheers :)